# Application of Fubini's theorem to bound a double integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f:\mathbb R \to [0,+\infty)$ belongs to $L^1(\mathbb R)$. Suppose also that $$\int_{E} f(x) dx \le k \quad \text{ where $E=\{x\in \mathbb R \text{ such that } |x|>c\}$}$$ for some fixed $c>0$.

Now, for $a >0$ fixed, I want to prove that
$$
\frac{1}{a}\int_{E}\int_{-\infty}^x f(z) e^{a(z-x)} dz dx \le k.
$$
(or some other constant that does not depend on $c$).

Is this true as a consequence of Fubini's theorem?

My guess that this should be true comes from the following related computation:
$$
a\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{-\infty}^x f(z) e^{a(z-x)} dz dx = \int_{\mathbb R} f(z) dz <\infty.
$$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a simple computation and the  OP would have been on the right track had he/she written $E$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ in the last identity.

Notice that
\begin{align}
\{(x, z): |x|>c, z<x\}&=\{(x, z): x<-c, z<x\}\cup\{(x, z): x<-c, z<x\}
\end{align}
Direct integration yields
\begin{align}
\int^{-c}_{-\infty}\int^x_{-\infty}f(x)e^{a(z-x)}\,dx\,dz&=\frac1a\int^{-c}_{-\infty}f(x)\,dx\\
\int^\infty_c\int^x_{-\infty}f(x)e^{a(z-x)}\,dx\,dz&=\frac{1}{a}\int^\infty_cf(x)\,dx
\end{align}
Hence
$$\int_E\int^x_{-\infty}f(x)e^{a(z-x)}\,dxdx=\frac1a\int_Ef\leq\frac{k}{a}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{E\cap (z,\infty)} e^{a(z-x)} dx\leq \int_{z}^{\infty}e^{a(z-x)} dx =\frac 1 a$ for each $z$, so (by Fubini's Theorem)  the double integral is at most equal to $\frac 1  {a} \int_E f(z)dz\leq \frac {k} {a}$.  So you can get $\frac k {a^{2}}$ as an upper bound.

Comment: Thanks! Where does $\int_{E\cap (z,\infty)}$ come from?

Comment: Also, when you write $\int f(z) dz$ do you mean $\int_{E} f(z)$ dz?

Comment: @mathqf That is right.